# Files erased in Xcode 4.2 (iOS5) still appearing when the simulator starts

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I was making a xib file with a custom name:

> SixthViewController

But later I decide to erase that file (I choose "Delete" not "Delete Reference only") and make a new file with the same name but with different objects. Though, when I run the simulator the old xib still appearing.

So, I've tried the typical solution:

1. Clean target, build and run: The simulator still using (running) the old xib.
2. Searching  the physical file and try to erase it, but obviously, if the xcode was able to let me create the file with the old name without any problems then the old xib file wasn't there. So, this option was discarded (I didn't want to erase the new file).
3. Using a different name for the file: I've created a new file with different name "SixthView" so when I'm calling the class, it works. Though, I want to use the old name...
4. Deleted the app from the simulator (I'm not using the device yet).

I've read that I need to search the file in the simulator

/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/

But didn't have succes with that.

Is there any other way to use a different file with the same name of the class erased?

I'm doing something wrong? (weird, because I did this once or twice before, till I renewed the XCode to iOS 5)

Answer (score 1):

I was just having this same issue only with my app icon. I had deleted the previous icon and was using a new icon, even with a different name, but when built, Xcode was still using the old icon.

My solution was a combination of two of your options:
1) Clean the build. Make sure you clean the same scheme you will be using to build
2) Delete the app from the device/simulator before running

Although I agree that neither of these seems to solve the issue, a strategic combination of the two seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you install an app during development through Xcode, it doesn't erase files in the bundle that are already there.  Delete the app from your device and it will remove the old files.  This works in the simulator just as it does on a real device - hold down on an app's icon until they shake, then hit the *x*.

Comment: I forgot to mention that step (which I did), but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to is search the project folder (type in the name of the project in the finder, then the project folder should be there) find the file that you want gone, and delete it.

Comment: That was the step 2. For real, nothing is working. Could be a bug from the new xcode, the fact is that I can't use that name for a file anymore.